# Covering space and classification

Tags: algebraic-topology

Is there any classification for all topological spaces that have $\mathbb{R}^n$ as their universal cover?

Comment: You're pretty much asking for a classification of groups acting freely, properly discontinuously on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: And the answer is "no, absolutely not". Every hyperbolic manifold is of this form, and the structure of those is very complicated.

Answer (score 4):

A more restrictive question has a more reasonable answer, namely a classification of all Riemannian manifolds that have $\mathbb{R}^n$, with the usual metric, as their universal cover. I think that these are precisely the complete [flat manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_manifold). Bieberbach classified all the closed flat manifolds: in particular, they all admit finite covers by flat tori $\mathbb{R}^n/\Gamma$ (where $\Gamma$ is a lattice). Their fundamental groups are [space groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_group).

As Mike Miller says in the comments, without this restriction the problem is at least as complicated as the problem of classifying [hyperbolic manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_manifold) (since hyperbolic space is homeomorphic and even diffeomorphic to Euclidean space), which is probably hopeless.

Comment: One thought: classifying oriented closed manifolds with $\Bbb R^n$ as their universal cover shouldn't be far off from the classification of $K(G,1)$s with an oriented closed manifold model (by the Borel conjecture, which is probably true), and these have a nice conjectural classification: the $G$ are precisely finitely presented Poincare duality groups. Other contractible manifolds without boundary should be too "asymmetrical" to usually admit compact quotients; I don't know any actual conjectures or theorems that make this idea precise. (There should be a non-orientable version too.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your helps. Actually, I want to consider this problem for those spaces that are free $\mathbb{Z}_2$-spaces. (a free $\mathbb{Z}_2$-space, is a topological space $X$ with fixed point free involution over it).

Comment: @123 I really don't think that helps. I can only imagine the added complication making a classification *worse*.